# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f_n(x)$ is uniform convergence in $(0,1)$
we have to prove that
$g_n(x) = f_n(x^2)$ is also uniform convergence in $(0,1)$.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Notice $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \geq \|g_n - f\|_\infty$ (since the right hand side is only taking supremum over $x^2$ as opposed to all $x$).

Comment: do you mean $|g_n - g|$ ?

Comment: By definition, $f_n \to f$ uniformly means that $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0$ where $\|f_n - f\|_\infty = \sup_x |f_n(x) - f(x)|.$

Comment: Yes, I know that. but in the right side you wrote $|g_n-f|$ and if we want the sup of $g_n$ we need do take it by $|g_n-g|$ no?

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant $g_n - g$ where $g(x) = f(x^2).$ Sorry, the main point is that if you constrain the domain of $f_n$ by a function not depending on $n,$ the uniform limit does not get affected. In general, $\|s - t\| \geq \|s \circ \varphi - t \circ \varphi\|$ for all $\varphi$ mapping some set into (but not necessarily onto) the common domain of $s$ and $t.$